# Why does initializing program throw this error ? ('Non-base' + BASE + ' character')

Tags: initialize

Im trying to initialize a deployed program and have been running into this error. [image]

Here is the command that the cli is executing.. [image]

Comment: please copy paste the code and the errors instead of posting images

Answer (score 1):

The arguments to your CLI command are being directly mapped into `PublicKey` instances, but the arguments themselves are:

```
--min-signatures 1 /Users/...
```

Which is obviously not base-58 compliant. You'll need to parse the keypair file path in the arguments list, read the file to get the keypair byte array, then instantiate it using `Keypair.fromSecretKey(<uint8array>)`. You can then get the public key from the keypair after its instantiated.